# PHP: Left Join 2 table and print all records

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table records in my database which look like this:

Table 1 with the column 1:

```
topic_id    name
21          my computer
```

table 2 with columns as follows:

```
reply_id    topic_id    message
    1           21       blabla
    2           21       blue
```

In which the topic_id column in the table 2 is the foreign key of the table 1

I wanted to echo all replies in the table 2 along with the topic name (#21) in the table 1. So, I made the query like this

```
$q="SELECT name, message
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.topic_id = table2.topic_id
";
```

However, the result/ output returns the topic's name and ONLY ONE reply, but not 2 (or all) as expected. Did I miss something?

I used LEFT JOIN because some topics are still waiting for replies. In case that there is not any reply, the topic's name is still printed in browsers.

I also tried adding

```
GROUP BY table1.topic_id
```

but still NO LUCK!

Can you help? Thanks

EDIT: To clarify the question I add the php code to fetch records as follows:

As you know, The name needs to be printed only once. So, I code like this:

```
$tid = FALSE;
if(isset($_GET['qid']) && filter_var($_GET['qid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range'=>1) ) ){

// create the shorthand of the question ID:

$tid = $_GET['tid'];

// run query ($q) as shown above

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($dbc) .     "<hr>\nQuery: $q");
if (!(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) ){

    $tid = FALSE; // valid topic id

}


}//isset($_GET['qid']

if ($tid) { //OK

    $printtopic = FALSE; // flag variable to print topic once

        while($content = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            if (!$printtopic) {
              echo $content['name'];
              $printtopic= TRUE;
           }

      }
} // end of $tid

// Print the messages if any:
echo $content['message'];
```

Comment: can u show your php code.

Comment: [**Fiddle shows 2 replies**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e332d/1) i guess the problem is in your php code how you are fetching the results ?

Comment: Put table2 as first in the LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Try this with inner join

```
$q="SELECT name, message
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.topic_id = table2.topic_id";
```

Comment: According to the provided sample data set it doesn't matter to use inner or left have you visited [*fiddle with left join*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e332d/1)

Comment: Yes. I think that the problem was in my php code to fetch records.

Comment: I just added the php code in the question to clarify it. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$q="SELECT table2.reply_id, table1.name, table2.message
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1
ON table1.topic_id = table2.topic_id
";
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this issue, I can find out that the problem is that I had to change the query to INNER JOIN and add the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE table2.reply_id = {the given topic_id}
```

Then it works well!

Sorry to disturb you all!